# Interface SIM 900A GSM MODEM with Raspberry Pi 2 Model B via I2C

Tags: i2c, raspi-config, gsm

I have bought [SIM 900A GSM MODEM](http://elementzonline.com/sim900a-gsm-modem-module-with-sma-antenna-rs232-ttl-i2c-output--74?search=SIM%20900A%20GSM%20MODEM). It is working perfectly on serial interface but it require an extra Serial to USB converter module. So I want to interface it with my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B via I2C Interface.

[image]

I am new to I2C Interface. Please suggest the connections/schematic or if I require to add any other module (Isolation system) in order to connect via I2C Interface as mentioned in (https://) youtube.com/watch?v=oTOIzdwE84k video.

Comment: Most likely, you will need 5v to 3.3v converter in between. There is no data sheet / manual available on that site and hence I can't say for sure. Also on their blog, they have used serial / UART to demonstrate how to make this module work with arduino / rpi.

Comment: @dastaan I have successfully tested it via serial / UART module. But I want to remove this dependency. Let me ask the seller for the datasheet. Between please check above posted image there is a 3 pin port named I2C. I found [this](http://imgur.com/XgxSdmy) schematic, please suggest if this is correct schematic.

Comment: This is how level shifting is done usually. http://playground.arduino.cc/uploads/Main/i2c-level-shift-mosfet.png

Comment: I got an another Idea to connect serial (Rx Tx) TTL output directly to RPi's GPIO (Rx Tx) as discussed [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=104457). Correct if I am wrong.

Comment: This blog : http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/ explains how to make connections without using level shifter however, I do not recommend it using without level shifter. Hope it helps.

Comment: You need to find the specification of the I2C messages.  There is little point in connecting the unit to the Raspberry Pi with I2C unless you know the I2C command/data messages needed to communicate with the device.

Answer (score -1):

You can interface gsm module to Raspberry pi using rs232 to usb convertor.. the below tutorial shows how to do the same.. 
http://learnraspberrypieasily.blogspot.in/2016/09/raspberry-pi-tutorial-part-10-how-to.html?m=1

Comment: The question does indicate specifically that the point of the exercise is to *avoid* using an extra converter.